# Visual Studio unable to open Web site error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I work with Visual Studio 2008 and work on a web project which contains a web site.
When opening the solution file, I receive the error message:

> Unable to open the Web site http://localhost/myWebsite.de. The Web site http://localhost/myWebsite.de does not exist.

I can see the web site greyed out, with the remark "unavailable", in the solution folder.

It is possible to add the web site to the solution, but after relaunching Visual Studio, it´s gone again.

Has anyone had this problem in a similar way?

Answer (score 11):

Open the existing Solution file using notepad, Copy the actual project Directory path and update the solution file content with respect to following options alone

```
Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "update the path here"
Release.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "update the path here"
SlnRelativePath = "update the path here"
```

leave the remaining config untouched

Comment: I also had to update the line starting with `Project("(<GUID>") [...]` and ending with a `GUID`, but otherwise this worked.

Answer (score 5):

I think [KB 326497](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326497) has your answer. Setting up an IIS virtual directory to point to the location the site is running from corrected this error for me.

Answer (score 2):

Question was probably not general enough to answer it...
Must have been some problem with my SourceSafe, after I copied the web site to a
local folder, I had no problems any more.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check with the host file located in "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc" directory. There might be chances for redirecting localhost to some other host environment by you or someone else.
  If you remove the line for localhost configuration it will work for you.