# Visual Studio Teams 2015 Git Error opening web project solution (Website does not exist)

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I am trying to set up a visual studio team web project for a small school project, however, I am getting some strange errors that I think may have something to do with the school network. I can sync to the repository, but when I try to open the solution on school computers an error appears saying that it no longer exists.

```
C:\Users\me\WebSites\HS-Website\ : error  : Error opening web C:\Users\me\WebSites\HS-Website\. Unable to open the Web site 'C:\Users\me\WebSites\HS-Website'.  The Web site 'C:\Users\me\WebSites\HS-Website' does not exist.
```

The error lists a file path that does not contain the repository or the solution. If I right click the solution and select "Open in File Explorer", the correct path and project shows up in the file explorer.

Actual File Path (The one opened when right clicking on the solution)

```
C:\Users\me\Documents\Source
```

In the solution explorer, it shows the solution name followed by "(load failed)". If I attempt to re-load the solution an error window pops up that says the project has been moved re-named, or is not on my computer.

I'm not entirely sure what the problem is here. The solution seems to work on non-school computers. The error message appears on all user accounts trying to open the solution after the repository is cloned. I have tried changing my repository file-path to match the location on the error, and tried moving it to different locations on the computer.

I really appreciate any help or suggestions, I am new to visual studio teams, and have not found any working fixes yet.

Comment: The solution file probably contains a relative path or an absolute path to the other location. Try opening the solution file in Notepad and correct the paths. Or remove the projects from the solution and add them again using "Add existing project" from the solution's context menu.

Comment: have read this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666133/visual-studio-unable-to-open-web-site-error)?

Comment: I think I might have fixed it by deleting the contents of the solution, and creating a new web project inside. I currently can't test the results from another user, but I will update in a few hours when I can get another user online. Thank you everyone for the help!

Comment: assure yourself that you added to the git repository all the files, in particular the .csproj one (that could have been the reason too). For a quick test, clone the repo on your computer on a different directory and verify whether you could open it, no need to wait for others.

Comment: It works on my computer, after some testing, it seems like it only happens on computers where no projects have ever been opened

Comment: @Ant Do you solve the issue with my solution?

Comment: @starain-MSFT Yes, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, for website project, the solution file path is different with website files’ path. You just add the solution file to the git server or solution file and website files are in different repository. Refer to these steps to deal with this issue:

1. Create a new repository in your VSTS git team project
2. Clone this repository to your local machine
3. Create a new website in VS and change the web location path to that local cloned path, you can copy existing website to cloned path
   [image]
4. Close vs or solution
5. Delete solution files in file system
6. Open VS > File > Open > Web site > Select your website folder (in cloned path)
7. Click Save, it will prompt a save dialog > save the solution file to the same path of website (in cloned path)
8. Commit and push changes